# Encryption Algorithm for PHP & Servelts

Tags: php, servlets, encryption, public-key-encryption

We are developing a web application using php/java servlets. i would like to pass encrypted variable from  PHP application to Servlet using $GET[] method and decryption from there.

Is there any encryption algorithm to use in both languages?

Edited**
How can i Use Mcrypt Algorithm to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use SSL, preferably with client side certificates.

Comment: Cant we do it  server side using in encryotion algorithm like mcrypt?

Comment: Yes, however you are likely to make a whole host of errors and would better be served with SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 1):

Any encryption algorithm can be used in any language. For HTTP requests the best option would be to use HTTPS - it will require configuration, rather than coding.

Comment: can we use mcrypt algorithm to encrypt decrypt in php and servlts

Comment: I guess. You'd have to implement it in java r look for an existing implementation. Looks like Resin has one: http://www.caucho.com/resin-4.0-javadoc/com/caucho/quercus/lib/mcrypt/Mcrypt.html

Comment: @Bozho: Java contains inbuilt security, or you can use bouncy castle. mcrypt is simply a library in use by PHP. I still strong do not suggest this route for the inexperienced.

Comment: @Yann yeah, I know java has built in security, but I couldn't see that this particular algorithm is supported.

Comment: @Bozho: mcrypt is not an algorithm. Its a library containing several well known symmetric algorithms.

Comment: aha, thanks: des, blowfish, arcfour, enigma, ghost, LOKI97, RC2, serpent, threeway, twofish, wake, XTEA. Then the OP should decide which one